# Oracle Error: inconsistent datatypes

Tags: select, oracle10g, intersection, ora-00932

I am using the following query in my ORACLE(10g) DB.

**SELECT * from student_table where student_no like '%STUDENT%' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT * from student_table where student_no in ('STUDENT1234','STUDENT5678')**

I got error like:
**java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB**

Any Idea how to resolve this Error?

Comment: You _are_ aware that, error notwithstanding, the intersect of those two will just be the result of the second query, aren't you? At least I think so. I could be wrong, It wouldn't be the first time :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are correct. If the comparisons or strings were different this could done with an "AND" in the where clause instead of an INTERSECT.

Answer (score 4):

I guess `student_table` contains at least one column with datatype clob.

You shoul not `select *` then, but only the non-clob columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do an INTERSECT when the result set includes any LOB.

In this case, however, you don't need the intersect anyway:

```
SELECT * from student_table
where student_no like '%STUDENT%'
and student_no in ('STUDENT1234','STUDENT5678');
```

And, as pointed out earlier, the first condition is redundant anyway in this particular instance:

```
SELECT * from student_table where student_no in ('STUDENT1234','STUDENT5678');
```